# Linear preconditioning on a symmetric and non-definite matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear equation $Ax=b$, such that $A = W+iT$ where $W, T $ are positive definite matrices, and I have an iterative method for solving the equation. Now I want to find a preconditioner for the method.

I know that if the matrix has a form $A = M-N$, where $A$ and $M$ are positive definite, than $M$ can be used as a preconditioner, because of:
$$\kappa(M^{-1}A) \leq \frac{1+\rho(C)}{1 -\rho(C)}$$
Where $C = I-M^{-1}A$ is the iteration matrix of the method, such that $\rho(C)<1$.
However, with my proposed equation, $A$ can't be a positive definite.

My question is: can you still make an argument that $M$ can be used as a preconditioner for the equation? Thanks to all who answer!

Comment: Good preconditioners inherit many of the properties of the original operators. If $A$ is not positive definite, it is doubtful that $M$ can be both positive definite and a good preconditioner. I do not believe that your question can be answered in the affirmative. Almost certainly, we need to know  more about how $M$ is constructed from $A$.

Comment: I'll tell you why I'm asking this. In the following article (Particularly after lemma 2.2 page 286), they conclude that $\Upsilon^{-1}$ can be used as a preconditioner for the matrix $A$, which is of the form that I've described. It seems that they have reached the conclusion based on the argument I've presented here, however, because $A$ is not positive-definite, I don't understand how they've reached this conclusion. ($\Psi$ is the iteration matrix)
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11075-019-00682-1.pdf

Comment: I think that you are attaching to much weight the authors choice of words. When they write "... hence $\Upsilon^{-1}$ can be used as preconditioner.", they are not implying that the preconditioner is good. They have $A = \Upsilon^{-1}( I - \Psi(\omega,\tau)$. where $I$ is the identity matrix. This suggests that there is a chance that the preconditioner might be good. Theorem 2.4 immediately gives conditions when this is true.

Comment: Why does Theorem 2.4 give conditions for it to be true? is it because the spectral radius of $\Psi$ is lower than 1? I'm just trying to understand the justification for the speculation that $\Upsilon$ can be used as a preconditioner.

Comment: Yes. Many iterative methods work well for matrices of the form $B=I-E$ where $E$ is small perturbation of the identity matrix. How one measures small is very context dependent. Having $\rho(E)<1$ is very weak condition and mainly of theoretical interest. If, say $\|E\|_2 \leq \frac{1}{2}$ then convergence is fast enough to have practical interest for a variety of methods.